# Two more words and their anagrams

Tags: word, anagram

Excluding the word SPINE, can you give me 2 words which are part of the human body that also have one word anagrams that are part of the human body?

Again, please exclude SPINE.

No partial answers. No slangs, abbreviations.

One of the two I found was a 4 letter word. I am sure there are more?

Comment: PINES are not part of the human body; they are a kind of tree.

Comment: @IanMacDonald There are other anagrams of Spine.

Comment: Yes, but SNIPE _also_ isn't a part of the human body.

Comment: LOL. Darn it. Must be the American english I used.

Comment: Leg and the other leg.

Comment: Pardon me for being out of context, but thread is so far the best of the jokes, I've ever came across :D

Comment: @LaconicDroid: SE needs to implement a "Hot Network Comments" feature just for you! :D

Comment: Still haven't found the intended 4-letter answer - unless it's the one suggested by APrough?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman. No it is not. I have 2 options. I can give it myself or turn that into a new puzzle. Still thinking

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are two word pairs that suit these criteria:

> **ELBOW**/**BOWEL**
>  and
>  **FINGER**/**[FRINGE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bangs_(hair))**

Comment: There is a 4 letter one too Stiv.

Comment: @DrD Okay, I'll see if I can find that one too...

Comment: Head and Hade? @Stiv

Answer (score 11):

How about

> ARSE and EARS

assuming British English is allowed.

Comment: I think the former is officially counted as slang, but realistically, its just part of british language so I think it should count :P

Answer (score 5):

I've found another four-letter example to those already given

> [SPIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saliva) and [PITS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axilla)

Answer (score 2):

A maybe rarer answer would be

> **CUSPID** (canine tooth) `->` **CUPIDS** (Short for Cupid's Bow, a double-curved upper lip)

and a more reliable; albeit informal answer:

> **GUMS** `->` **MUGS** (someone's face; informal)

Answer (score 2):

Another one to add:

> **TORSO** -> **ROOTS** (as in hair or teeth - hey if "FRINGE" counts, this is no less valid.)